# Errors installing GCC 4.3.4 on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

When installing GCC 4.3.4 on Ubuntu 11.10, following [these instructions](http://quox.org/install/gnu/gcc-4.3.4.html), I am encountering many errors at the `make` stage. The full dump is [here](http://pastebin.com/VAg9QfAF), but the important parts seem to be some missing files, starting with:

```
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388:23: error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:33:
/usr/include/stdio.h:36:25: error: bits/types.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../../.././libgcc/../gcc/libgcc2.c:33:
```

Does anyone have any ideas why these can't be found? A google search indicates they are standard C headers.

(N.b. at the configure stage I had to install dependencies GNU MPFR and GMP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the libc-dev package.

Comment: Hmmm... I already seem to have that. (`Note, selecting 'libc6-dev' instead of 'libc-dev' // libc6-dev is already the newest version.`)

Comment: I guess something went wrong with your gcc compilation/installation process. Why don't you try to install gcc from package to see if everything works and in that case you have to go through the installation of gcc-4.3.4 again.